# Kendo grid unable to handle script tag data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo grid. Some of the data I am getting has script tag in it. I have set column encoded property to true. Still it is not encoding script tag.

You can try this small smaple.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name", encoded: true }
  ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "<script>Jane Doe</script>" } ]
});
</script>
```

Comment: May I ask *why* the script tags?

Comment: I am getting that script tag data from some other source which I cant control

Answer (score 2):

Try stripping those `<script>` tags in the [`dataSource.schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) event, where you can manipulate dataSource's data before it's been used to render the widget:

```
schema: {
    parse: function(data) {
        data.forEach(x => x.name = x.name.replace(/<(\/?)script>/g, ''));

        return data;
    }
}
```

Note that the `replace` is made specific for `<script>` tags, other tags won't be managed. Regex isn't the best way to handle html, but in case of a specific tag it's ok.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UhICU)